# Picking a photo from gallery and show in a image view

Tags: android, image, android-gallery

I have an app, which has a button to select a photo from your gallery and it works fine and after selecting the image my app show came back to the activity and shows the image in an image View.

Every is working fine but sometimes ,when i select some particular images the preview is not showing. I have also tried to compress the image still its not working

My code is below..
**In `onCreate()`**

```
galeryBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGallery);
galeryBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

    }
});
```

**In onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)**

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image

    // Show the Selected Image on ImageView
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I run into similar problems like getting cursor uri from resource, open stream, set bitmap etc. And it has bugs all the time.

So I searched libraries and found image-chooser-library library.

I bet you would like to try this project from [image-chooser-library](https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library)

It is very easy to use and solves all those nitty gritty problems for you, like images from picasa etc.

Hopefully it is useful for you.

Comment: i have tested your but when i select some images from phone it giving toest "file not found"

Comment: Did you select images from highlight?  Is so, check out dev_get_content branch and see whether it works.

Comment: Hey also if you think there is a bug, you can create an issue there :) The author will appreciate your effort.

Comment: thank you for the code, Ur code is working absolutely fine. I have tested it

Answer (score 6):

Try like this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        switch (requestCode) {
                case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmapImage =decodeBitmap(selectedImage );
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                                // Show the Selected Image on ImageView
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);

            }
```

And

```
public  Bitmap decodeBitmap(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 100;

        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
    }
```

Comment: Your Code is work well.But how to increase the with and Height of the ImageView?

Answer (score 3):

The way you're trying to load a bitmap in `onActivityResult()` is not absolutely right. Sometimes you will not be able to open an image and your application can crash. You'd better use code like this:

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
InputStream imageStream = null;
try {
    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle the error
} finally {
    if (imageStream != null) {
        try {
            imageStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Ignore the exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

```
imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
```

It work for me.